# jquery .not() is executing even though it shouldnt

Tags: jquery

Here is my fiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/k0za95nw/2/

basically if **"#original_items li"** has a class name of "**aa**" I want it to skip this `<li>` and go to the next `<li>`.

```
       if (jQuery("#original_items li").not(".aa")) 
    {
// (does not have a classname of .aa, run code here)
// but unfortunately code here is running even if the LI has a classname of aa

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the list of items?  Because the `.not` statement returns a list of elements...

Comment: In your fiddle, the if statement will always true since you are targeting all `li` without the class of `aa`.

Comment: How do I exclude any LIs that have a `aa` class?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the items?  If you just want a jquery list of all the elements without the `aa` class, then do `var elems = jQuery("#original_items li").not(".aa");`

Comment: I am kind of new to jQuery, basically, I in the fiddle, I don't want to "catch" the menu's LIs as that is causing problems

Comment: Change `if($('li').not('.aa'))` to `if(!$(this).hasClass('aa'))`  .. is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Nope, it still does not work :(
My original fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dNfsJ/ but when I add the menu code it does not work so I want to exclude it from processing the Menus LIs

Comment: What is the end result you're going for? If I do what I said to your fiddle, the 1 and 2 blocks don't have stuff underneath...

Comment: End result: I don't want those extra boxes under box 3

Comment: `.not()` returns you a jQuery object.  When you use `if`, it converts it to a boolean.  A jQuery object will *always* convert to "true".  You want to check if the `.length` of the object is (or is not) `0`.

Comment: Then why did you add the extra menu?  If all you want to do is hide the boxes, then add a CSS rule: `.aa { display: none; }`

Comment: Here's the same fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k0za95nw/3/ ,I deleted the font line so it looks better. Basically, in the 3rd box I want to have a menu like this: http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/ but it wont let me do that if it "catches" the menus LIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of a confusing fiddle. What if you try using

```
if( !jquery(this).hasClass("aa") ){
 #something
}
```

Comment: `.hasClass` doesn't need the `.` for class names, you can use `.hasClass("aa")`

Comment: Nope, it still does not work :( My original fiddle is here: jsfiddle.net/dNfsJ but when I add the menu code it does not work so I want to exclude it from processing the Menus LIs

Answer (score 2):

This is for all li without aa class:

```
var items = $("#original_items li:not(.aa)");
if (items.length > 0) 
{
   //run code here
}
```

and for your function try this:

```
jQuery("#original_items li").each(function () {

if ($(this).hasClass("aa")) //all <li class="aa">
{
   // do something
}
else
{

            var item = jQuery(this);
            var item_clone = item.clone();
            // 'store' the clone for later use...


            alert("here");
            item.data("clone", item_clone);

            // set the initial position of the clone
            var position = item.position();
            item_clone.css("left", position.left);
            item_clone.css("top", position.top);

            // append the clone...
            jQuery("#cloned_items").append(item_clone);

        }        
    });
```

Comment: Please look at my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k0za95nw/3/ and answer according to how I change the code there as I am pretty new to jquery and the whole point of this question is to get that working

Comment: Basically, under box 3 I want to have a menu like the one thats here: http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/ but it won't let me do that as it's "catching" that menus LIs and converting it to boxes as well...

Comment: @Ryan sounds like you have more of a css problem

Comment: Yes @chris, I don't understand the problem at all

Comment: This is my pastebin: http://pastebin.com/jY19EBUw of the full file, its a mess, which is why I posted just the snippet. But if you are sure its a CSS problem I'll accept your answer as personally, I am not sure what the problem is :(
I'm just too raw to understand such advanced jquery stuff I guess, Im still learning

Comment: @Ryan you have all boxes because your css says make all li elements 100px wide with a height of 90px. You need to differentiate between first level li and second level. One way is to write css for .aa to override the li css. You may want to open a new css question if you have trouble with that.

Comment: Thanks, will do! I've also chosen your answer as it was first and seems correct judging by the votes... thanks again!